# Post hoc tests for robust mixed design ANOVA using R

Tags: r, mixed-model, repeated-measures, robust

Is it possible to compute the function `mcp2atm` with unequal sample size? I ran the robust Mixed Design ANOVA by using `tsplit` and want to do post hoc tests now.

Answer (score 3):

The robust mixed-design ANOVA function is now called `rmanova` instead `tsplit` and unfortunately the WRS2 package does not yet contain a corresponding post-hoc test for it. (`mcp2atm` is solely for `t2way`). In case you need to conduct a post-hoc test, you must use the original WRS package for now.

This package contains the functions `bwmcp` for multiple comparisons of variable A (between), B (within) and the interaction between these two. If you are interested just in one of these you can use `bwamcp` for A, `bwbmcp` for B respectively `bwimcp` for the interaction. The usage of these function is not as straightforward:

```
# load the latest WRS package
> source("https://dornsife.usc.edu/assets/sites/239/docs/Rallfun-v38.txt")

# convert your data for the function from long format into list format. 

> data <- bw2list(yourdf, 4, c(7,8))

# In this example "4" stands for the column where your independent groups are located.
# c(7,8) indicates the position of the columns with the within groups data
```

Now that we have the data prepared suppose that our between subject variable has 3 levels (groups) and our within-subject variable (as seen above) has 2 levels. The function would then look like this:

```
> bwmcp(3,2, data, tr = 0.2) # uses by default 20% trimmed means
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the WRS2 package and run the following posthoc tests: sppbb (within effects p), sppba (between effects), and sppbi (interaction effects).

You can read more about it here: https://link.springer.com/article/10.3758/s13428-019-01246-w

Comment: These functions are not post-hoc tests for the robust mixed-design ANOVA `rmanova`. As you can read in the WRS2 documentation, these tests are omnibus tests just like the function `rmanova` except that they are separate, use bootstrap and a modified one-step estimator by default (instead of a 20% trimmed mean).